# How to reinstall Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The config directory for rails was accidentally deleted.  Now any attempt to run rails produces the following:

script/rails:5:in `require': no such file to load -- /Users/user/config/boot (LoadError)
    from script/rails:5

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new rails empty project with `rails new project_name` in a separate directory then copy that `config` directory into yours and update the files as needed

Comment: that should do it if this is the only thing wrong with your current rails app setup.